# EFG fails to generate after database was restored

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-database-first

I am using entity framework core .Net 2.2 and Microsoft SqlServer 2017 and am trying to update models generated by entity framework code generator (database first approach). I was able to initially create all my entities and mappings. I made changes to the database and did a restore using a .bkp file to update the copy on my local sql server instance.

After the update, I use the following cli command in package manager console,
efg generate -c "Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=SOLA_DEV;Trusted_Connection=True;"

but I get the following error. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or where to start investigating? It is telling me Instance failure but I am connecting fine to it. I've tried making sure the schema was updated in sqlserver, all of my updates are visible after the backup. I've tried creating a new solution and generating from the same database but I get the same error.

```
12:48:21 I Loading options file: generation.yml
12:48:21 I Loading database model ...
12:48:21 F Host terminated unexpectedly
System.InvalidOperationException: Instance failure.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseModelFactory.Create(DbConnection connection, IEnumerable`1 tables, IEnumerable`1 schemas)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, IEnumerable`1 tables, IEnumerable`1 schemas)
   at EntityFrameworkCore.Generator.CodeGenerator.GetDatabaseModel(IDatabaseModelFactory factory) in C:\projects\entityframeworkcore-generator\src\EntityFrameworkCore.Generator.Core\CodeGenerator.cs:line 248
   at EntityFrameworkCore.Generator.CodeGenerator.Generate(GeneratorOptions options) in C:\projects\entityframeworkcore-generator\src\EntityFrameworkCore.Generator.Core\CodeGenerator.cs:line 41
   at EntityFrameworkCore.Generator.GenerateCommand.OnExecute(CommandLineApplication application) in C:\projects\entityframeworkcore-generator\src\EntityFrameworkCore.Generator\GenerateCommand.cs:line 76
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.Invoke(MethodInfo method, Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.OnExecute(ConventionContext context)
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<Apply>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.<>c__DisplayClass142_0.<OnExecute>b__0()
   at EntityFrameworkCore.Generator.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\projects\entityframeworkcore-generator\src\EntityFrameworkCore.Generator\Program.cs:line 50
```

The generation.yml file has not changed since it was generated.

```
  namespace: '{Database.Name}'
  directory: .\
database:
  connectionName: ConnectionStrings:Generator
  userSecretsId: //Removed for example
data:
  context:
    name: '{Database.Name}Context'
    baseClass: DbContext
    namespace: '{Project.Namespace}.Data'
    directory: '{Project.Directory}\Data'
  entity:
    namespace: '{Project.Namespace}.Data.Entities'
    directory: '{Project.Directory}\Data\Entities'
  mapping:
    namespace: '{Project.Namespace}.Data.Mapping'
    directory: '{Project.Directory}\Data\Mapping'
  query:
    generate: true
    indexPrefix: By
    uniquePrefix: GetBy
    namespace: '{Project.Namespace}.Data.Queries'
    directory: '{Project.Directory}\Data\Queries'
model:
  shared:
    namespace: '{Project.Namespace}.Domain.Models'
    directory: '{Project.Directory}\Domain\Models'
  read:
    generate: true
    name: '{Entity.Name}ReadModel'
  create:
    generate: true
    name: '{Entity.Name}CreateModel'
  update:
    generate: true
    name: '{Entity.Name}UpdateModel'
  mapper:
    generate: true
    name: '{Entity.Name}Profile'
    baseClass: AutoMapper.Profile
    namespace: '{Project.Namespace}.Domain.Mapping'
    directory: '{Project.Directory}\Domain\Mapping'
  validator:
    generate: true
    name: '{Model.Name}Validator'
    baseClass: AbstractValidator<{Model.Name}>
    namespace: '{Project.Namespace}.Domain.Validation'
    directory: '{Project.Directory}\Domain\Validation'
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, if you have an instance failure, typically that means that you have something wrong with your connection string. Once that was fixed the code generated as expected.